# Are these invalid iOS Provisioning Profiles an issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I dont know why, how and when but this is the situation today in my developer console:

[image]

Now I need to update my application but Im scared that because of this situation, my app won't work anymore like it should (for example push notifications).

Can anybody tell me what's going on, if this is a problem with my update, if I must fix it, or whatever...?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue. Xcode has a tendency to invalidate lots of profiles when you click "Fix" sometimes when there is an issue. You can go in to the profiles, edit them and recreate them without any adverse effects.

You can use Sigh which seems a good way of managing your profiles: https://github.com/KrauseFx/sigh